# What is the reason for this error Invalid pointer dequeued from free list?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

When i added a subview to a view i got crash with the following stack. I could not find the exact reason for this error? the mac application is running in 10.10.5. During the search i found that this issue occurs in 10.10.5. Can any one help me to debug this issue?

```
Application Specific Information:
abort() called
*** error for object 0x600000a24ea1: Invalid pointer dequeued from free list


Thread 0 Crashed:: MainThread  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff96bb2286 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff9358cb53 abort + 129
2   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00007fff97eadf3c nanozone_error + 524
3   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00007fff97e9ba5c _nano_malloc_check_clear + 370
4   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00007fff97e9db48 nano_calloc + 73
5   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00007fff97e9dacb malloc_zone_calloc + 78
6   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00007fff97ea3231 calloc + 49
7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8e09fc12 class_createInstance + 133
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8e0a1dea +[NSObject new] + 42
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff90ab2a04 _NXSetCursorRect + 408
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff90ab26c6 -[NSWindow _addCursorRect:cursor:forView:] + 907
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff90ab231a -[NSView addCursorRect:cursor:] + 555
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff90cf88eb -[NSTableHeaderView resetCursorRects] + 389
13  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff90aaf3ef -[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 663
14  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff90aaf899 -[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 1857
15  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff90aaf899 -[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 1857
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff90ab04ee -[NSScrollView _updateTrackingAreas] + 119
17  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff90aaf899 -[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 1857
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff90aaf899 -[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 1857
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff90aaf899 -[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 1857
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff90aaf899 -[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 1857
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff90aaf899 -[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 1857
22  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff90aaf899 -[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 1857
23  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff90aaf899 -[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 1857
24  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff90aaf899 -[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 1857
25  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff90ab04ee -[NSScrollView _updateTrackingAreas] + 119
26  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff90aaf899 -[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 1857
27  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff90aaf899 -[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 1857
28  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff90aaf899 -[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 1857
29  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff90aaefb2 _handleInvalidCursorRectsNote + 1077
30  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff91132231 __35-[NSWindow _postInvalidCursorRects]_block_invoke3353 + 46
```

Comment: Google and you'll find this suggests memory has been overwritten and malloc, the underlying memory allocator, is damaged. As to whether it is your or a system bug you'll have to did deeper yourself. Check any uses of pointers (as opposed to object references), `free` if you use it, etc. Good hunting!

Comment: Show some source code and explain if you are using ARC or not.

Comment: Source code is huge and do not know where is it crashing. we are using ARC. I have got the crash only once during the the run and is not reproducible after that.

Comment: You said "When i added a subview to a view..." so do you do that in code?  If so, that's the code I'd like to see.

Comment: it is just the basic code. addsubview. we are not doing any thing else in that method.